# Добавление переменных в MySQL запрос в коде PHP

Tags: php, mysql, select, переменные

Можно ли использовать переменную в MySQL запросе вот такого вида:

```
SELECT *  
FROM articles  
WHERE id_cat ='.$_GET["id"].' AND id_sec = '.$sect_num.'
```

В которой $sect_num должна быть $section['id'] (полученное из другого запроса значение). И где нужно объявлять эту переменную? Сейчас везде получаю ошибку  `"mysqli_fetch_all() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in"`, понятно, что запрос не видит переменную и не может быть выполнен, но я не понимаю, куда нужно ее добавить, чтобы его удалось выполнить

Получается, что если объявить ее не в том куске, где используется $section, то значение $sect_num будет неверное, а если в нем, то не удается использовать ее для следующего запроса в MySQL

Comment: Используйте PDO и подготовленные выражения http://phpfaq.ru/pdo

Comment: Вы бы весь код показали, хотя конечно для начала прочтите то, что написано по ссылке выше. Но похоже, что у вас в корне не верный подход. Не должно быть ситуации, когда вы в запрос select пытаетесь передать переменную, содержащую результаты другого запроса. SQL очень мощный язык и позволяет получить любые необходимые вам, связанные данные одним единственным запросом.

Comment: Судя по тексту ошибки у Вас ошибочно выполнен предыдущий запрос и вместо данных получено Булевское (нихт)

Comment: Хотя формально не хватает кавычки в самом начале. То-ли не докопировали, то-ли ошибка...